# удаление и запись обьектов в json файл

Tags: angularjs

Я сейчас изучаю ангуляр и немного, возможно, не так понял метод $`http.delete`

Запущен локальный сервер. 
Есть `json` файл. 
Я хочу методом `delete` удалить из него некоторые объекты, или методом `put` дописать, такое ж возможно?

Правильно ли я понял работу этих методов?
Позволяют ли они изменять json файл?

1. Я подумал что если методом `GET` я могу получить массив, то `DELETE` и `PUT` удаляют и кладут в него елементы массива, верно?
2. Или нужно полученный массив записывать в переменную и уже с ней работать?
3. Получится что после перезагрузки страницы все пропадет, как вариант можно записать в `localstorage`, но возможно в `angular` есть какие-то другие способы о которых я не знаю пока что?

Answer (score 2):

Как следует из названия $http.delete осуществляет запрос DELETE по протоколу [HTTP](https://www.wikiwand.com/ru/HTTP) на сервер. Если стоит задача изменить json файл на сервере, то вам нужно обработать входящий запрос и удалить требуемый объект из файла. Для записи новых объектов предполагается использовать метод POST, а PUT или UPDATE служит для изменения существующих объектов, можно почитать об этом [здесь](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST)
Для лучшего понимания советую сначала ознакомиться с протоколом http и rest, думаю все станет понятней.
Так же укажите на чем у вас работает локальный сервер (php, node.js, asp.net ...)